# Definition of "localized state"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, definition, quantum-states, locality

Is there a definition of a localized state in quantum mechanics? I've seen that some textbooks use this term, but they don't give a definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A localized state of a particle or a field means the same thing as in semi-colloquial context: it means that most of the energy density (for the case of a field) or most of the probability (particle, quantum mechanics) may be found within a region (e.g. a ball) whose linear size is smaller (or much smaller) than the total size of the material (and surely smaller than infinity).

The opposite term is a delocalized state – e.g. a plane wave – in which the particle may be found anywhere in the material or anywhere in space.

Comment: I suppose there's no "hard", precise definition?

Comment: The ‘hard’ definition, when you can make sense of it, is that a localized state is a vector in the Hilbert space. A delocalized state is not normalizable so it doesn’t belong to the Hilbert space.

Answer (score 0):

Newton and Wigner had a more precise definition.

https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=wigner+newton&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-jp&client=safari

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).